# No ask question icon

Tags: feature-request, design

I've just come across this site (annoying for me considering half my work has involved using SharePoint...) and it looks great - though it seems a bit odd (for me anyway) that there is no icon

> [image]

Also here on meta too

> [image]

Sorry to be so niggly, otherwise the site design is quite awesome :)

I'm using Firefox 61, and tried it in Chromium 67.

Comment: wow good catch :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, that's odd. But not all that troublesome. Our sister site
 https://ux.stackexchange.com/ use no icons whatsoever, but make the Ask action look like a button. Here, we use a different color to make the ask action stand out.

But I agree with you, it should have an icon to emphasize its use.

Comment: I think most SE sites use a theme like that I think (though sites like Electronics.SE use to have the same button on each), its just the inconsistency that get me :-)